# How do I remove these unexpected Render Artefacts?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I hope to find help here. I am working on a project, and didn't touched the file for a while. Now starting againI started rendering a test image and those horrible artefacts occur over the render process.

Does anybody has any clue where that can come from? The last time I rendered it there was no problem at all.

I am rendering on a mac, cycles, supported, GPU compute.
Sampling rate was 1000. Denoising is NLM.

I have absolutely no clue.

Thanks in advance, hope you can figure it out.

[image: Render Artefacts]

Comment: AMD graphics card? Latest drivers? Recommend switch to OpenImageDenoise.

Comment: can you provide blend file? i have a mac too...so i can check it out